# Repository w/ View Model returning null on one property

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I’ve searched for this for a number of hours, but can’t find what I’m looking for answer wise. I have the following:

(Repository.cs)

```
public class AppRespository
{
    private DataContext db = new DataContext();

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> LoadStates()
    {
        var query = from d in db.States.ToList()
                    select new SelectListItem
                    {
                        Value = d.StateID.ToString(),
                        Text = d.State.ToString()
                    };
        return query;
    }
}
```

DataContext.cs

```
public class DataContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<States> States { get; set; }
}
```

ViewModel (States.cs)

```
public class States
{
    [Key]
    public int StateID { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> State { get; set; }
}
```

Controller (ApplicantController.cs)

```
// GET: /Applicant/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        AppRespository repo = new AppRespository();
        States viewModel = new States();
        viewModel.State = repo.LoadStates();
        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

View:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model=>model.StateID, Model.State, "select")
```

Why is it when debugging my application I get a null on this line from my repository class?

```
Text = d.State.ToString(),
```

State is always null, while StateID is always getting set. I have successfully loaded this drop down before using just my model and controller, but I like this pattern. I'm intermediate w/ ASP MVC so I'm probably missing something.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you post the code for the `States` entity?  It might be a simple `.Include(x => x.State)` on your EF query.

Comment: @chappoo The code above for my states entity is all I have. I thought surely I was implementing this right, now I'm starting to doubt myself. The only place I'm doing an EF query is in my AppRepository.cs class.

Comment: It would be useful to know your intent with the d. State property. It looks like you expect it to be a string but it's an IEnumerable. Also it's normal to define both a data poco and an appropriate view model for the desired view

Comment: @chappoo: Yes, I expect it to be a string. I bet this is where my confusion arises. I'll take a look at what is being offered up here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need to move things around a bit here.  I'm making some assumptions about what you want to achieve, but

(Repository.cs)

```
public class AppRespository
{
    private DataContext db = new DataContext();

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> LoadStates()
    {
        var query = from d in db.States.ToList()
                    select new SelectListItem
                    {
                        Value = d.StateID.ToString(),
                        Text = d.State
                    };
        return query;
    }
}
```

DbContext

```
public class DataContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<StateEntity> States { get; set; }
}
```

State Entity

```
public class StateEntity
{
    [Key]
    public int StateID { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
}
```

ViewModel

```
public class StateModel
{
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> States {get; set;}
}
```

Controller Action

// GET: /Applicant/

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    AppRespository repo = new AppRespository();
    StateModel viewModel = new StateModel();
    viewModel.States = repo.LoadStates();
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

Hopefully this helps get you most of the way there.  I'm assuming you want to just load a list of int / string pairs with the StateEntity

Comment: I'll definitely look at this example. I'm obviously misunderstanding something in this approach.

Comment: thanks, I finally got it working. That's one more layer I wasn't expecting.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(n => n.StateID, 
                     new SelectList(State, "Value", "Text"))
```

Comment: Tried that and it still errors on my repository class, on the State property.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your query. Instead of:

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> LoadStates()
{
    var query = from d in db.States.ToList()
                select new SelectListItem
                {
                    Value = d.StateID.ToString(),
                    Text = d.State.ToString()
                };
    return query;
}
```

Have this:

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> LoadStates()
{
    var query = from d in db.States
                select new
                {
                    StateID = d.StateID,
                    State = d.State
                };
    var result = from q in query.ToList()
                 select new SelectedListItem
                 {
                     Value = d.StateID.ToString(),
                     Text = d.State.ToString()
                 }

    return result;
}
```

The first part of the query sets up a query to get the data from the database the way it's stored there. It uses an anonymous class with 2 properties: `StateID` and `State`.

Once the query is ready, we call `query.ToList()`, which actually runs the query and gets the data, and then makes a list of our anonymous class objects.

Now we can select from the list and convert the data from the anonymous objects to `SelectedListItem` using `.ToString()` or any other .NET method.

Comment: If I change the query as mentioned I get: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression. I did a google search on that yesterday and it was suggested to have the ToList called after the database call of States. For some reason, the State property of my view model doesn't get pulled in by entity framework inside my repository. If I switch that data type on it (string) it does. But surely this works with the current view model approach.

Comment: Is `SelectedListItem` your type, or built-in type? Normally you would have an entity class (to get data from the database), and a model class (to convert and present the data the way you need). I will modify my answer with an example.

Comment: SelectedListItem would be built-in type. Have an entity class (DataContext.cs) that gets/sets States view model, pulls back StateID ok. Guess I'm not completely following your statement.

Comment: Hmmm...using your code I get: The specified type member 'State' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported. Is this because of it being a property type SelectListItem?  I'll look around on that error as well. Appreciate the help.

Comment: Yes, it is because of that. But how is it stored in the database? Just to clarify: in the database you have a table with an int column (StateID). How is the State (which is a StateListItem) stored?

Comment: State is stored as a varchar in the db.